# Can I have multiple values in a single variable?

Tags: javascript, html

As the title "Can I have multiple values in a single variable?"

First, I have got this form:

```
<form name="myform">
 <input type="text" name="mytext">
 <input type="button" onClick="clickButton()">
</form>
```

Then, take a look at my script.

```
<script>
function clickButton() {
  var x = document.myform.mytext.value;
  var a = 13;
  var b = 17;
  var c = 19;

  if (x == a) {
    alert('hello');
  } else if (x == b) {
    alert('hello');
  } else if (x == c) {
    alert('hello');
  } else {
    alert('goodbye');
  }
}
</script>
```

Is there any way to make one variable with multiple values? Like, `var myvalues=1,2,3;`

Comment: Use an array? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: No there is not such a variable. But you can use `array` or even `object`.

Comment: Another option would be using strings, you can enter in your textbox `"1,2,3"` and then in `if` statements look for those substrings

Comment: Why is this question voted up? Clearly no research made..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct response to your question would be to use an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). But from what you're trying to do, Looks like your looking for an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_overview), specifically the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors):

```js
function clickButton() {
  var x = document.myform.mytext.value,
    greetings = {
      "13": "hello",
      "17": "hello",
      "19": "hello"
    }
  alert(greetings[x] || "goodbye");
}
```

```html
<form name="myform">
  <input type="text" name="mytext">
  <input type="button" onClick="clickButton()" value="greet">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is an `Array`. An array is a variable that can hold mutiple values and/or elements. You can assign to it your values and then use the `[n]` selector where `n` is a number between 0 (first element) and 2 (in this case is 2 because you've only got 3 variables, so their positions will be 0, 1, 2).

Then, to make your code clearer, you can use the `switch()` statement to check the values and execute some code when a certain value is found.

Here is an example:

```
function clickButton() {
    var x = document.myform.mytext.value,
    values = [13, 17, 19];

    switch (x) {
        case values[0]:
        case values[1]:
        case values[2]:
            alert("hello");
            break;

        default:
            alert("goodbye");
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use a object and give callbacks on values

```
  function abc(val){

      alert(val);
  }

 var doSomething = {
    "1": abc('1');,
    "2": abc('2');,
    "3": abc('3');
  }
```