# Javascript - How to put variables inside a string that's assigned to a variable?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to start some localization for my project and I just realized I don't know how to do a simple thing of putting a variable inside a string for my locale variable.

My original string inside `app.js` is `` `Input must be between ${props.minValue} and ${props.maxValue}.` ``

E.g.

```
let errorMsg = `Input must be between ${props.minValue} and ${props.maxValue}.`
```

and I'd like to assign this to a variable `INPUT_MUST_BE_BETWEEN` inside `en.js` such that my code will now look like

```
let errorMsg = validation.INPUT_MUST_BE_BETWEEN
```

where my `en.js` looks like

```
define({
  validation: {
    FIX_ERRORS: "Please fix the errors.",
    SPECIAL_CHARACTERS_NOT_PERMITTED: "Special Characters not permitted.",
    WHITESPACE_NOT_PERMITTED: "Special Characters not allowed.",
    REQUIRED_FIELD: "This field is required.",
    INPUT_MUST_BE_BETWEEN: `Input must be between and .`,
    NOT_A_VALID_URL: "Not a valid URL"
  }
}
```

How can I insert two variables in to `INPUT_MUST_BE_BETWEEN`?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean? The variables will be "inserted" when you create the template.

Comment: Just do the assignment: `INPUT_MUST_BE_BETWEEN = \`...\` `

Comment: Make `INPUT_MUST_BE_BETWEEN` a function that takes the 2 parameters and returns the string with the values interpolated.

Comment: @MinusFour Is that an acceptable practice for an object inside my localization file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is highly unclear.

I personally believe that you should use one of the many packages you can find to add i18n to your app (for example, I see you're using props, so in react you could use https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next)

Anyway if I understood correctly, you can turn `INPUT_MUST_BE_BETWEEN` into a function and pass those two variables to that function in order to return the correct string:

Eg:

`` function INPUT_MUST_BE_BETWEEN(min, max) { 
  return `Input must be between ${props.minValue} and ${props.maxValue}.` 
 } ``

But again, your question is very unclear, try to edit it so that I can solve your problem :)

UDPATE:

The code you showed can be refactored like so:

```
define({
  validation: {
    FIX_ERRORS: "Please fix the errors.",
    SPECIAL_CHARACTERS_NOT_PERMITTED: "Special Characters not permitted.",
    WHITESPACE_NOT_PERMITTED: "Special Characters not allowed.",
    REQUIRED_FIELD: "This field is required.",
    INPUT_MUST_BE_BETWEEN: (min, max) => `Input must be between ${min} and ${max}.`,
    NOT_A_VALID_URL: "Not a valid URL"
  }
}
```

Point is that I wouldn't do it like this. I'd use the tag functionality of the template literals (have a look at this post for example: https://jaysoo.ca/2014/03/20/i18n-with-es2015-template-literals/)

Point is, again, I wouldn't use a personal solution at all, I showed you a package to use in these situation, I'd go for it.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I've updated my question to maybe shed some more light into what I'm trying to do

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll look into link :-)

Answer (score 0):

To keep retain readability, I would use minValue and maxValue. But if you need them in a single variable, an array or an object are your options.

See: [Can I have multiple values in a single variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27578472/can-i-have-multiple-values-in-a-single-variable)